# Object returns its constructor instead of false in JS. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, object

Please help me to fix the working of my script.

```
function KittyFactory(kitty) // kitty constructor
{
    for (x in kitties)
    {
        if (kitties[x].color == kitty.color)
        {return false;} // if already in the array return false
    }
    return kitty; // else return the object itself
}

function iPreferDifferentKitties(kitty)
{
    if (new KittyFactory(kitty))
    {
        kitties[x].push(kitty);
    }
}
```

But if the `(kitties[x].color == kitty.color)` is `true` the `new KittyFactory(kitty)` will be an empty constructor (the function itself) instead of a huge `FALSE` what i want.

My problem is basicly i can put to my kitties array two kitties with the same color. :( Makes me sad.

Could you help me please how should i use it?

Comment: Why are you using a constructor here? You want a plain function that returns something - you're not constructing any object.

Comment: Because the kitties going to play with their skein later.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but `kitty` is passed to the constructor. So the constructor doesn't construct anything because the kitty object is already available. Sounds like you just want to remove the `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return `false` from a constructor. When you invoke a function with the `new` operator, the return value must be an object. If you try to return something else, it behaves as if there were no `return` statement (and the newly constructed object is returned by default).

Comment: Wonderful. I'll find other ways. :) Thanks

Comment: You may return `{ retval : false }`, that would work. Or return an empty object `{}`.

Comment: Ye, i did the same maybe a brilliant otherguy knows a different way. I wanted the solution because i did not want to put legs on my Kitty until i know it will be in unique color. :D

Comment: What about now using `new` at all, as `pimvdb` suggested? You don't seem to need it, at least on the example code you posted (no references to `this` inside the constructor).